# Probability of a set of experimental results occurring by chance

Tags: statistics

I’m writing to find out how improbable the following result actually is.  It has significance for the cause and cure of a debilitating condition called chronic fatigue syndrome, most of whose sufferers have been written off as crazy.  I don’t think all (or even most) of them are.

17/51 objects are of class A

20/51 of objects are of class B

9/17 class A objects are also of class B

What are the chances of this happening assuming all choices are random?

Here is the actual data on which this is based — but it’s highly technical.  Ned is Norman Sharpless, the new head of the National Cancer Institute.  Back in June he wrote a review on cellular senescence which gave me the idea that chronic fatigue syndrome was due to cellular senescence — suggesting both a diagnostic test and (even better) a therapy.  We’ve had correspondence back and forth.

Lewis Robinson M. D.

Ned:

Last week’s PNAS contained an editorial and a study on CFS which measured some 51 cytokines and adipokines in a huge number (192) of patients and an even larger number of age and sex mateched controls (392).  Here are the references [ Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. vol. 114 pp. 8914 - 8916,E7150 - E7158 ’17 ].  17/51 cytokines had levels which correlated with the degree of symptom severity (just the way DeMaria correlated p16^INK4a levels after chemotherapy with fatigue).   I looked up the 74 components of the Senescence Associated Secretory Phenotype (SASP) in Annu. Rev. Pathol. vol. 5 pp. 99 - 118 2010.  Then I looked at the 51 cytokines and adipokines tested in the paper, and tried to find which of the 51 were also in the SASP.   This was not a trivial task as frequently cytokines and adipokines have many different names.

20 of the 51 were in the SASP.  The most interesting point is that greater than 50% (9/17) of the tested cytokines/adipokines whose levels correlated with symptoms were in the SASP.  One would have expected 20/51 * 17 or 6.6 by chance alone.  While the difference between 7 and 9 isn’t great, I think it still remarkable.

Answer (score 1):

Your data can be placed in a *contingency table* that tabulates objects according to membership in class A or class B:

```
     A notA
B    9   11 
notB 8   23
```

If the observed objects are sampled at random from some larger population, you can use a statistics package to test the hypothesis that membership in class A is independent of membership in class B. Here's code in `R`, using two approaches: Pearson's Chi-squared test, and Fisher's exact test:

```
> dat <- matrix(c(9,8,11,23),ncol=2)
> dat
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    9   11
[2,]    8   23
> colnames(dat) <- c("A", "notA")
> rownames(dat) <- c("B", "notB")
> dat
     A notA
B    9   11
notB 8   23
> chisq.test(dat)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  dat
X-squared = 1.2442, df = 1, p-value = 0.2647

> fisher.test(dat)

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  dat
p-value = 0.225
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.6059657 9.1412158
sample estimates:
odds ratio
  2.311153
```

Both approaches yield a non-significant result, with p-values well above 0.05. Interpretation: if independence holds, the observed count of 9 in the (A,B) cell is not that unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Comment:  I believe the Answer by @grand-chat (+1) should settle whether the
data indicate significant association between conditions A and B.
However, there have been controversies about Yates's continuity correction (saying
it leads to unnecessarily low power) and the interpretation of the
exact test (on grounds it is a 'conditional test'). So here are results
from Minitab, where continuity correction is not used for the chi-squared test.

Additionally, in the Minitab output, Expected
counts appear beneath Observed counts. These expected counts may have given rise to
the comment that 7 (6.77) are expected by chance, whereas 9 were
observed. Perhaps "Remarkable," but not statistically significant.

Failure to reject the null hypothesis (independence) based
on so little data does not mean there is no connection between A and B--only that
the data at hand do not confirm statistical significance.

```
Chi-Square Test for Association: Worksheet rows

Rows: Worksheet rows   Columns: Worksheet columns

         A    not A  All

B          9     11   20
        6.67  13.33

not B      8     23   31
       10.33  20.67

All       17     34   51

Cell Contents:      Count
                    Expected count


Pearson Chi-Square = 2.015, DF = 1, P-Value = 0.156
Likelihood Ratio Chi-Square = 1.995, DF = 1, P-Value = 0.158
```